# Check whether data inside data folder android

Tags: android, android-file

Im doing a function where I record my voice then I save it into the data folder. Managed to work around saving into the data folder. But now my problem is that I need to check whether there is that specific data in the data folder so that I can do some stuff.. This is my code and not sure where went wrong:

```
            individualFile = "y1";
            OUTPUT_FILE= mydir + "/"  + individualFile;

            try{
                File file = this.getFileStreamPath("y1");
                if(file.exists()){

                     Log.v("Oh yes the thing is here", OUTPUT_FILE);
                      Share();

                }else{
                    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                 //Error message
            }
        }
```

What I need is that to check if the recorded file is already inside the data folder and if it is, then i need to show the Share() else I need to show the button for recording.

Comment: What is the exact problem ? An error / exception ? Please specify.

Comment: Im trying to check whether the file exist and I think I managed to do that already.. Do you know how to retrieve hence playing an audio file from /data folder in android because Im kindda stucked at that now..